# ExressJS res.redirect only redirects to its own URL

Tags: node.js, express

My ExpressJS is deployed in Windows IIS 2012 and the NodeJS version is v12.18.4 Below is my code snippet..

```js
app.get("/downloads", async function (req, res) {
  return res.redirect('https://google.com/');
}
```

But it  will redirect only to my root domain. When I tried in my Mac with Node version v10.16.0.. It is just fine..

But with windows.. It will just redirect to the root domain like example.com

I want to know why it is behaving like that in my Windows? The code looks correct.

**UPDATE**

- When I try to access https://myhost.com:8081/downloads it is fine. So I think my IIS URL Rewrite plays a part here

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to return while trying to send a response to the client.

Documentation [Here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

```
app.get("/downloads", async function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).redirect('https://google.com/');
}
```

Comment: It is still the same. I have updated my question